# Concurrency in a Libgdx app

Tags: java, android, concurrency, libgdx

I'm making an app that will have a lot of sprites to update with a lot of updates. Of course updates need to happen before everything is drawn. The more sprites, the harder it is on the main thread. I've been reading a lot of material on concurrency, but still not quite sure where exactly to start. The app is primarily for Android, but I would like to keep it cross-platform. So I can't really use any of the Android concurrency solutions (or can I?)

Is there something specific for Libgdx? Or should I just dive into java.util.concurrent?

Pardon my ignorance, but can someone please stick me in the right direction?

Comment: For LibGDX specific I think you need to read this http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/ and use LibGDX once to know how beautifully it manages things.

Comment: About how many sprites are we talking here? 100? 500? This won't be a problem at all for performance and you should not try to optimize anything for multithreading until you know that there is a bottleneck on your CPU. Furthermore you will probably have more problems with memory than your actual CPU, so you should consider using an Entity-Component-System which specializes on a good memory layout.

Comment: I have 50 custom sprites already. Each one has arrays of properties that need to be set up and consistently updated. The drawing is already staggering as the updates don't get drawn simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe if you had 500 custom sprites with lots of properties you might experience slow down on a really low end device. I wouldn't worry about this until you're sure it's a problem. I don't think LibGDX has helper classes for concurrency, so you would be on your own with it.

Comment: 50 Sprites is no problem at all, and I think 500 also wouldn't be on any device nowadays. Probably you are using something like `new Texture("...")` or `spriteBatch.begin()/'end()` for every sprite or something like that.

Comment: Maybe there is another bottleneck in your code? With Java VisualVM you have a free profiler. Its shipped with the JDK (bin folder).

Comment: @noone, you were right. There was another issue with my code. It's a little silly in hindsight, but I guess I learned quite a bit reading all the info about concurrency and opengl rendering. Thanks!